# Fitnesse + WebDriver: any working solution?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, fitnesse

Could you please tell me if there were any attempts to integrate Fitnesse and Selenium WebDriver? I'm looking for something like Selenesse (https://github.com/marisaseal/selenesse), but for WebDriver, not "old" Selenium.

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 1):

I used to use [Fitnium](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fitnium/) when I was doing work with Fitnesse and WebDriver early on, I found it did not scale well for the types of tests I was doing but it may work for you.

I was testing a Login and Registration system, the pages used a lot of JSON and I had issues getting the timing right so the pages would load with the right drop downs or complete the personal profiles.  The Registration system also was reused for a Profile/MySite system and I was hoping to reuse code here; though that did not work well.  This was on a SharePoint site and was a few years ago.  I found that just using WebDriver and C# code was more stable, especially when using the Page Object model.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what tests it does not scale well for and why?

Answer (score 0):

From the information you give above it looks like Xebium may be your answer.

http://xebia.github.io/Xebium/